# Has anybody recently made Google Maps work on localhost in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have wasted several hours in vain. Some Stack Overflow answers elsewhere say that Google documentation is incorrect. However, their suggestions did not work for me. I still get this error:

> Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized: http://localhost:3000/addresses/1

How am I supposed to do it on a Rails application in development mode?

I have tried various combinations of **Application restrictions** and I can not make it work. How do I correctly set up my API_KEY and it's restrictions? The UI has changed and the old answers do not help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, make sure you add `localhost:3000/*` to the "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)" field. It's a little awkward to get this to save if I remember correctly.

Here's a screen shot of my settings that are working:

[image]

Comment: It worked. Also, for some strange reason while I was trying to edit it I got redirected to a page that enables Google Maps JavaScript API. I wonder if there was a problem. Was the API not enabled? The interface is awful. One thing that I miss most is the time when new setting will be activated.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I don't get into the Google Cloud Console very often so I always have to re-learn how it's organized so I know what you mean about the interface.

Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you out.